# Why does vanilla js appendChild work, but jQuery .append does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3zgfbqav/

I have a click function that I can't get to work in jQuery alone - only a mix of vanilla JS and jQuery. It is working, but I'd like to understand why I can't get it all done in jQuery.

```
//I couldn't get a jQuery equivalent of this function to work so I left it in vanilla js
function createWidgetScriptElement(symbol) {
    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    scriptElement.async = true;
    scriptElement.src = 'https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js';
    scriptElement.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({
            "symbol": symbol,
            "interval": "1m",
            "width": 425,
            "colorTheme": "light",
            "isTransparent": false,
            "height": 450,
            "showIntervalTabs": true,
            "locale": "en"
        });

        return scriptElement;
    }

$('.ttlink').on('click',function(e){
    var symbol = $(this).attr('data-href');
    var widgetScriptElement = createWidgetScriptElement(symbol);
    $('#target').empty();
    document.querySelector('#target').appendChild(widgetScriptElement);
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

I couldn't find jQuery equivalents for the first function - so I left it the only way I could get it to work. In the click function, when I combine the empty and append in jQuery syntax

```
$('#target').empty().append(widgetScriptElement);
```

I get several errors in console such as "embed-widget-technical-analysis.js?_=1577484658696:1 Widget settings parse error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" and "Invalid settings provided, fall back to defaults" that I only get when I attempt to use jQuery to simplify the emptying and loading of the #target div.

Comment: _"I get several errors in console"_ - Please show us any relevant errors. Also make sure your question contains _everything_ we need to reproduce your problem within your question itself. Your question becomes invalid for future visitors if it has to rely on 3rd party websites.

Comment: Ive been 'scolded' by people on here before for putting too much code - so I link to the jsfiddle that has ALL the code. I will add the errors to the question.

Comment: SO has build in JSFiddle functionality just the same. It's perfectly fine to use that instead

Comment: OK Ill use your preferred method going forward. I hope this will suffice for now.

Comment: It's not my personal preference. It's just to have a useful record of your question for future visitors with the same question. Anyway, quite busy right now to fully check what's going on. However, my best guess is this: _"By design, any jQuery constructor or method that accepts an HTML string — jQuery(), .append(), .after(), etc. — can potentially execute code. This can occur by injection of script tags or use of HTML attributes that execute code"_. Most likely it's not just appending, but also executing the code.

Comment: Including a [mcve] is part of writing a good question, not just people's preference.

Comment: Got it, I haven't used SO's built in JSFiddle functionality. Will definitely use it going forward. Thank you both for getting me on track.

Comment: Your `createWidgetScriptElement` function returns a script element with both a source attribute and script (inserted with innerHTML). It should be one or the other, not both.

Comment: It works fine as it is - I was asking how to make it work in jQuery syntax instead of a mix of jQuery and vanilla js. You can see it is working if you look at the js fiddle link I posted.